# What happens when exception occurs in a thread in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, threads, exceptions

I want to know how Tomcat works.
As I know Tomcat assigns a thread when receiving a request from clients.
Then what happens when exception occurs in a thread in tomcat?

All threads in tomcat die due to the exception?

I have another question.
Tomcat run new JVM process when receiving a request from clients?
or.. it just uses its thread to handle the request?

Answer (score 0):

I checked by myself.

1. Server don't die when an exception in a thread occurs.
2. It seems embedded tomcat and my spring app run in one single JVM.